# Changing template after a site has been created (SharePoint 2007)

Tags: 2007, site-template

I have created a site using the option "Blank Site" under the "Collaboration" tab, is it possible to change the template to "Publishing Site" under the "Publishing" tab while still preserving the content?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to change the template to an existing site. Even if you apply the manual changes but the underlying site would still be based on the original site template.